# How to design search bar?

Tags: enyo

I have a search bar on the top of a page where user can type any word. I want to display the names of the songs which contain the word typed by user. How to design this using enyo.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made a little fiddle with comments especialy for you :)
http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/NEYQC/

```
enyo.kind({
    name: 'App',
    kind: enyo.Control,
    components: [
        {kind: 'FittableRows', components:[
           {name: 'footer', kind: 'onyx.Toolbar', components: [
               {kind: "onyx.InputDecorator", components: [
                       {kind: "onyx.Input", name:"inputfield", placeholder: "Search number"},
                ]},
                {kind: "onyx.Button", content: "Search", ontap: "search"}, 
           ]},
            {kind: "List", fit: true, name:'list', classes:'list', count: 20, fixedHeight: true, onSetupItem: "setupItem", components: [
               {name: "item", classes:'listitem', ontap: "itemTap", components: [
                   {tag:'span', name: "name", content:"song name"},
                   {tag:'span', name: "index", content:"", style:'float:right;'}
                ]},
            ]},

        ]}
    ],
    searchstring:'',
    search: function(inSender, inEvent) {
        console.log('search tapped');
        console.log('inputfield value: ', this.$.inputfield.getValue());
        console.log('list: ', this.$.item);
        console.log('searchstring: ',this.searchstring);
        this.searchstring = this.$.inputfield.getValue();
        this.$.list.refresh();

    },
    setupItem: function(inSender, inEvent) {
        // just to have something to fill in
        var data = ['alibaba', 'alibobo', 'alibibi'];
        this.$.index.setContent(inEvent.index);
        this.$.name.setContent(data[inEvent.index %3]);
        // if searchstring isn't emty get to work
        if(this.searchstring != ''){
            var regex = new RegExp(this.searchstring); // = /searchstrin/g

            if(this.$.name.getContent().search(regex) != -1){ // -1 = not found
                this.$.list.select(inEvent.index, true); // set state selected true      
            }
            // if selected = true change add css class
            this.$.item.addRemoveClass("listitemselected", inSender.isSelected(inEvent.index)); 
        }

    },
    itemTap: function(inSender, inEvent) {
        alert("You tapped on row: " + inEvent.index);
    },

});​
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this fiddle! One quick(?) question: any idea why the list isn't scrollable? If the fiddle results area is shorter than the list, you cannot access the remaining rows, by mouse or keyboard, on the browsers I've tried (Chrome and Firefox on Linux).

Comment: good point... the fit:true seems not to work on the component with name 'list' if you set a fixed height by adding: style:'height:100px', for example, then the scroller shows up... I'm going to investigate some more on why the flexible height of fit:true won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

i got a sample posted here as part of my enyojs tutorial, but it uses a third party library called taffyDB [here](http://www.isgoodstuff.com/2013/08/07/enyojs-tutorial-11-3rd-party-combo/)